# Bash, searching in all pdf files

Tags: bash, pdftotext

I want a script that would find my everything what I want in all of my pdf files. So I wrote this

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in */*.pdf; do
printf "$file\n"
echo "--------------------------------------------"
pdftotext $file - | grep -i "$1"
echo "--------------------------------------------"
printf "\n\n"
done
```

But there are some problems. Firstly I'd like to see only those files that grep find something in, also I noticed that PdfToText throws a help messeges when it encounters a filename with white spaces

Comment: You could try `grep --files-with-matches --text "searchkey" path/*.pdf` (`grep -la ...`), but this doesn't convert the PDF to text, assumes the searchkey wouldn't be found in the binary of the PDF, and assumes the text is contiguous.

Comment: Maybe you can use `pdfgrep`?

Comment: well, that's also a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few issues here.

- Your script will spew errors if filenames include a percent sign, since `printf "$file"` will interpret its first argument as a format.  Use `printf '%s' "$file"` instead.
- You haven't quoted the filename argument when you run `pdftotext`, which is likely why it throws its help message -- `pdftext foo bar.pdf -` looks like two arguments, not one filename.  `pdftotext "$file"` instead. (As a rule, always quote your variables in bash.)
- If you want to show output only for matching files, you need to evaluate a condition before you print the filename.

I don't know how `pdftotext` behaves exactly, but assuming it doesn't produce a bunch of stderr, the following might work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

line=$(printf '%032s' 0); line=${line//0/-}

for file in */*.pdf; do
  output="$(pdftotext "$file" - | grep -i "$1")"
  if [ -n "$output" ]; then
    printf "%s\n$line\n%s\n$line\n\n" "$file" "$output"
  fi
done
```

Note: I haven't tested this. You might want to expand the `printf` with the `$line` references for readability if this format appears complex or obtuse.